# Use of the "Object" data type in C#, does it contain members?

Tags: c#, json, oop, object, deserialization

I am a little confused as to the use of the keyword "object" using in C#. What can and can't it be used for. Can you access a member?

For example, I have made a small snippet of code to deserialize a JSON string.

```
public static object DeserializeString(string jsonstring)
{
    // Deserialize the data
    object testObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(jsonstring);
    return testObject;
}
```

When I use the deserializer to create an object I can not access any memebers.
I know that this may be a silly question because I haven't defined a class with any members to want to access it. I am trying to avoid making dozens of classes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you call `GetType().ToString()` on the object, what do you get?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm and/or https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: `I am trying to avoid making dozens of classes` is the opposite mindset of what you should have. More often than not, you want more classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am a little confused as to the use of the keyword "object" using in C#. What can and can't it be used for. Can you access a member?

C# is by default a *statically typed language*. That is, if you have an expression of a particular compile-time type you may access only the members of that type. This is a safety system; it is saying "I only have a guarantee that the members of this type are available, so prevent me from accessing any other members".

If you have an expression of type `object` then you may access the members of `object` -- `ToString`, `GetType` and so on.

If you want to turn off this safety system, use `dynamic` instead of `object`, and you can then call any member you like; if you call a member that does not exist, your program will crash.  **When you turn off a safety system the safety system is turned off and you become responsible for guaranteeing safety**.

---

CLARIFICATION: Commenter Brian correctly points out that in the *specific* case of JSON objects, the default behaviour of a bad dynamic member access is to produce null rather than crashing; of course, much of the time after producing null because a member is unexpectedly missing, the next thing that will happen is a null dereference crash, so there's actually not a whole lot of additional safety margin there, but there is at least some.

---

My question to you was:

> If you call `GetType().ToString()` on the object, what do you get?

The answer was `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`.  So in this case you can access the members of that type like this:

```
JObject jo = (JObject)testObject;
```

(Assuming you have `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` in your directives.)

Again, your program will crash if the object is not actually of that type.

You can do a safe type test with:

```
if (testObject is JObject jo)
{
  var r = jo.Root;
  ...
```

> I am trying to avoid making dozens of classes.

C# is a statically-typed language; it encourages creation of classes.  Again, this is a safety system. Invest in its correct usage!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good answer! I agree with all of your responses, however the last one seems short. I think a more full answer would be to also find the correct usage via the correct design patterns just for those who don't know what correct is. Study design patterns is a great next starting point for the readers. Again, that's a better answer than I could have come up with.

Comment: I'll note that `JObject` implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, so using `dynamic` allows access to properties of the json itself; it's giving you more than you'd get out of casting to `JObject`.  Assuming explicit types are used to avoid ambiguity, trying to dynamically access missing properties of a `JObject` responds with `null`, rather than throwing an exception.  Nonetheless, I would rather use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomObject>`.  Even if you don't care about type safety, you might care about IDE features (find references, intellisense, refactoring, etc.).

Comment: @Brian: Good points all. `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` is my all time favourite interface name. I was asked to review the implementation and documentation when it was first created and my initial reaction was "that is the worst name I've ever heard"; I mean, sure, it does what it says on the tin -- it provides dynamic meta objects! -- but it is so intimidating and jargonish. Then I reflected a bit more. **That's exactly what we want**. We want the name to say "if you don't understand exactly what this is doing, do not touch it! This is a sharp tool!". :)